# Changing the value of a set field in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Is there a way to manually change the value of a field if it has been assigned a value?

for example, if var numberofcars = 5 and is set to a text field to show the 5, is there  way to overwrite that `textfield` to use your own value?

```
    <RowEditingTemplate>
    @{
    context.Total=context.Quantity*20;
    }
    
      <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Total">
                <MudNumericField Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" on Format="0.0" @bind-Value="@context.Total" Required="true" RequiredError="" />
            </MudTd>
    
      <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Quantity">
                <MudNumericField Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" on Format="0.0" @bind-Value="@context.Quantity" Required="true" RequiredError="" />
            </MudTd>
</RowEditingTemplate>
```

In the code above, I make `context.Total` equal to `context.Quantity*20` so if the user entere quantity 1, the total will become 20. What I want to find out is if there is a way to change that set value to anything else in the total field?

Comment: Can you show the code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I have updated the question. Hoping it makes it a little clearer :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
<RowEditingTemplate>
    <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Total">
        <MudNumericField Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" on Format="0.0" @bind-Value="@context.Total" Required="true" RequiredError="" />
    </MudTd>
    
    <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Quantity">
        <MudNumericField T="int" Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" on Format="0.0" Value="@context.Quantity" ValueChanged="(value) => HandleQuantityChanged(context, value)" Required="true" RequiredError="" />
    </MudTd>
</RowEditingTemplate>

@code {
    // Change YourContextClass with the type of your own data
    private void HandleQuantityChanged(YourContextClass context, int value)
    {
        context.Quantity = value;
        context.Total = value * 20;
    }
}
```

When `quantity` changes `total` is updated to `quantity * 20` but you can just set any value to `total` "manually".

Comment: Would this let you change the value of Total without it keep triggering the calculation of Quantity*20?

Comment: Yes, but why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: It works! however, if I change the quantity after changing my total, it goes back to normal :(

Comment: What do you mean "it goes back to normal"?

Comment: if you manually overwrite the total value but then change the Quantity after that, the total value changes to the calculated value again :(