# Manually adjusting the value in a field that has a set value already

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor, can you have a textfield set to equal to a value like a number then have the ability to manually change the value even though it has a defined set value?

Comment: How is this different from your other question? [Changing the value of a set field in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866094/changing-the-value-of-a-set-field-in-blazor)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change what a text box is showing, without modifying the value in code, right?

I don't think you can actually change which variable the input is bound to.

One way would be to have two textboxes. One bound to the value and one bound to a different value, and switch which one you display depending on what you want the user to see. Something like this:

```
@if(showOriginalTextbox == true){
    <!--Show the textbox with the real value-->
    <input type="text" @bind="realValue">
}
else{
    <input type="text" @bind="fakeValue">
}
```

Set fakeValue to whatever you want to display and showOriginalTextbox to false to show it.